# SID in a Powershell function

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell function that will enable auditing on the Perflogs folder. The function works just fine on a Windows PC with an English installation language. But when I use it on a Danish version it fails because "Everyone" doesnt exit on a Danish installation. On a Danish installation "Everyone" is called "Alle"

So instead of using everyone, then I would like to use the SID "S-1-1-0"

S-1-1-0 = Everyone/World [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649(v=vs.85).aspx)

But for some reason this also does not work. Does anyone have a clue about this and why I can’t do this?

```
function AddAuditToFile {
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path
)

Get-Acl $path -Audit | Format-List Path,AuditToString | Out-File -FilePath 'file_before.txt' -Width 200 -Append
$File_ACL = Get-Acl $path
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule("S-1-1-0","CreateFiles,Modify,AppendData”,"none","none",”Success")
$File_ACL.AddAuditRule($AccessRule)
$File_ACL | Set-Acl $path
Get-Acl $path -Audit | Format-List Path,AuditToString | Out-File -FilePath 'file_after.txt' -Width 200 -Append}
```

I call the function like this:

```
AddAuditToFile "C:\Perflogs"
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when trying with the SID or does it seem to complete all right just not actually make any changes?

Comment: `"S-1-1-0"` -> `(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::WorldSid), $null)`

Comment: I get an error. and the script dosnt continue.
cant remember error thoug :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `SecurityIdentifier` class to translate the SID:

```
$everyoneSid= New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier "S-1-1-0"
$everyoneSidName= $everyoneSid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$everyoneSidName.Value
```

This will output the actual everyone group name depending on the actual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Gungnir from Spiceworks found the solution.

I had to translate the SID and make a variable and then use the variable

> $AccountSID = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList 'S-1-1-0'
>
> $AccountName = $AccountSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
>
> $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule -ArgumentList ($AccountName,'CreateFiles,Modify,AppendData','none','none','Success')